# device-side assert triggered when training a transformer model

Tags: pytorch, nlp, transformer-model

I think this line (self.target_vocab_projection = nn.Linear(self.d_model, self.ff_size, bias = False)) made this error. However, when I change it to (self.target_vocab_projection = nn.Linear(self.ff_size, self.d_model, bias = False)), my model didn't work

```
class TransformerNMT(nn.Module):
    """ Neural Machine Translation Model with Transformer:
        - Encoder with stacked self-attention and feedforward layers
        - Decoder with stacked self-attention, encoder-decoder attention, and feedforward layers
    """
    def __init__(self, d_model, n_heads, ff_size, n_layers, vocab, dropout_rate=0.2):
        """ Init TransformerNMT NMT Model.
        @param d_model (int): Hidden Size, the size of hidden states (dimensionality)
        @param vocab (Vocab): Vocabulary object containing src and tgt languages
                              See vocab.py for documentation.
        @param dropout_rate (float): Dropout probability, for attention
        """
        super(TransformerNMT, self).__init__()
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.n_heads = n_heads
        self.ff_size = ff_size # feed forward
        self.n_layers = n_layers
        self.dropout_rate = dropout_rate
        self.vocab = vocab

        self.src_embedding = None
        self.tgt_embedding = None

        self.transformer = None
        self.target_vocab_projection = None

        ### YOUR CODE HERE 
        ### TODO - Initialize the following variables IN THIS ORDER:
        ###     self.src_embedding: Transformer Embedding Layer used for source language
        self.src_embedding = TransformerEmbedding(len(vocab.src), self.d_model, self.dropout_rate)
        ###     self.tgt_embedding: Transformer Embedding Layer used for target language
        self.tgt_embedding = TransformerEmbedding(len(vocab.tgt), self.d_model, self.dropout_rate)
        ###     self.transformer: Transformer layer
        self.transformer = nn.Transformer(d_model = self.d_model, nhead = self.n_heads, dropout = self.dropout_rate)
        ###     self.target_vocab_projection (Linear Layer with no bias), mapping hidden representation to the vocab distribution
        self.target_vocab_projection = nn.Linear(self.d_model, self.ff_size, bias = False)``
Can explain me why happened and how to fix it?
```

Comment: Please add the full traceback